# How to sum values from a python multidimensional array based on an element in the array?

Tags: python, list

Say i have an `array` called my array

`my_array= [[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]]`

I want to add all the second element from each sub-list starting with 1 so that my output would be 5

Also using NumPy is not an option...

Does anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a conditional list comprehension for this.

```
my_array=[[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]]
my_sum=sum(v[1] for v in my_array if v[0]==1)

print(my_sum)
```

Output:

```
5
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension with a filter to select the items, then sum them:

```
result = sum([b for a,b in my_array if a == 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the arrays and check if the first element is `1`, then add the second element to a variable:

```
result = 0
for i in range(0, len(my_array)):
    elem = my_array[i]
    if elem[0] == 1:
        result += elem[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_array= [[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]]
sum = 0
for x in my_array:
    if x[0] == 1:
        sum+=x[1]

print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

OP can't use numpy, but that does not have to be true for future readers of the question. Since we already have the non-numpy solutions covered, here's one with numpy.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> my_array = np.array([[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]])
>>>
>>> np.sum(my_array[:,1][my_array[:,0] == 1])
5
```

Answer (score 0):

For large data, converting to, or even better, using numpy from the beginning might be faster. Here, to_select is true if the corresponding element in to_sum is to be added:

```
my_array = numpy.array(my_array)
to select = my_array[:,0] == 1 
to_add = my_array[:,1]
result = numpy.sum(to_add[to_select])
```